# Is there a better way to code a worksheet-styled paper?

Tags: spacing

Lately I've been writing my own review homework/tests in LaTeX to store in my digital notes. All this time I just wrote all my problems vertically, like so (Suppose w, x, y, and z are arbitrary equations):

[image]

and I realize now that doesn't look good and it wastes a lot of space, so I figured writing my problems horizontally would be better. Here's what my code looks like

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
    \usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amyssymb}
       \usepackage{kantilipsum}
  \begin{document}
1) w$ \hspace*{2cm} 2) $x$

\vspace{1cm} 3) $y$ \hspace*{2cm} 4) $z$

\end{document}
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Even though I got pretty much what I was looking for, is there a "better" or more "professional" way of doing this?

Comment: You have many list environment, or you can have a look at exam-related packages.

Comment: Have a look at the `tasks` package.

Comment: You could put each problem into a \parbox, minipage or \makebox with a given width, using \hfil or \hfill to fill in the gaps.  Back when I was doing this, I used custom commands  for everything.  See http://www.elfsoft2000.com/worksheets/coordinate%20pairs.pdf for example.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Do you know how to add horizontal spacing within a `\parbox`? I've been looking and can't find anything on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier to show than explain.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% or use \noindent a lot

\newlength{\mylength}% compute once, use often
\setlength{\mylength}{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth - 0.5\columnsep}% two columns separated by \columnsep

\begin{document}
\parbox[t]{\mylength}{1) $w$}\hfill% expands to fill gap
\parbox[t]{\mylength}{2) $x$}\par\vfil% expands the same as the bottom of the page
\parbox[t]{\mylength}{3) $y$}\hfill
\parbox[t]{\mylength}{4) $z$}
\end{document}
```